# CoreData: difference between backgroundContext and child context with privateQueueConcurrencyType?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

With CoreData you can ask the container to create a background context with `container.newBackgroundContext()`.

This is useful for use core data in background without impact on the UI main context.

You can also create a child context with `privateQueueConcurrencyType`

```
let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

In this case if I'm not wrong, the context will still execute in background on a different queue.

So what's the difference between the two and when to use one and the other one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initialization of a context, namely:

```
let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

was commonly used before the introduction of [NSPersistentContainer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer). See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background, where they state:

> **Initializing and Configuring Contexts** For both contexts, the
>   initialization of the NSManagedObjectContext instance is the same: let
>   moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:<#type#>) The parameter
>   being passed in as part of the initialization determines what type of
>   NSManagedObjectContext is returned. When you use the
>   NSPersistentContainer, you configure the viewContext property as a
>   main queue
>   (NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
>   context, and configure the contexts associated with
>   **performBackgroundTask(_:) and newBackgroundContext()** as a private
>   queue
>   (NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType).

The documentation of [newBackgroundContext()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640581-newbackgroundcontext) says the following:

> Invoking this method causes the persistent container to create and
>   return a new NSManagedObjectContext with the concurrencyType set to
>   NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType.
>   **This new context will be associated with the
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator directly and is set to consume
>   NSManagedObjectContextDidSave broadcasts automatically.**

`newBackgroundContext()` does the same as your provided code, and something extra that I have highlighted in the above quote.

When developing for iOS 10+, I would recommend using `NSPersistentContainer` and use `newBackgroundContext()` when you want to block the calling thread, or `performBackgroundTask` if you do not want to calling thread to block when you want to dispatch work to the background.

I haven't worked with CoreData before iOS 10, but I think you need to do more stuff to make the context work when initializing it just with a `concurrenyType`. That isn't needed anymore with `newBackgroundContext()`.

Comment: I’d add to @J. Doe’s answer... watch WWDC 2019 video [“Making Apps With Core Data”](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/) at 6 minutes 5 seconds in, the verbal description of the convenience method `.performBackgroundTask` “creates a background context for you and disposes of it automatically when your block returns”.