# Relationship in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm a newbie in CoreData and I can't figure out what is the problem in my code. I call a function that downloads a large set of data (in CSV format) from a website and converts them into Core Data objects.
When I try to set a relationship (To-One) with User Entity an error occurs after some iterations.

```
var tasks: [Task] = []

let pc = PersistenceController.shared
func task() async {
    do {
        let urlArray = ListURL.urlTest
        for url in urlArray {
                let taskData =  url.lines.compactMap(Task.init)
                for try await task in taskData {                    
                    tasks.append(task)                  
                }
        }
                
        try pc.privateContext.save()    
        try await pc.viewContext.perform {
            try self.pc.viewContext.save()
            self.pc.viewContext.refreshAllObjects()
        }
    } catch { 
        //Error
    }
}


// in PersistenceController init
 privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
 privateContext.parent = viewContext
 privateContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

This is the Task initializer:

```
// Example of csv: (taskID,text,userID)  123456,some-text,987654
extension Task {
    convenience init?(csv: String) async {
        guard csv != "" else { return nil }
        let fields = csv.components(separatedBy: ",")
        guard fields[0] != "" else { return nil }
        
        let privateVC = PersistenceController.shared.privateContext
        self.init(context: privateVC)
        
        self.taskID = fields[0] 
        self.text = fields[1]
        
        let userID = fields[2]
        
        // Fetch request that return -> User?
        if let user = await searchUser(withID: userID, context: privateVC) {
            self.user = user  // Error after some iterations EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        }
    }
}

func searchUser(withID: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) async -> User? {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", withID)
        request.fetchLimit = 1
        var user : User?
        do {
            try await context.perform {
                user = try context.fetch(request).first ?? nil
            }
        } catch {
            // Error
        }
        return user
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit off topic but how many users do you have? Perhaps it would be better to preload the users into a dictionary with user Id as key instead of executing a fetch request each time.

Comment: It was my first test, but it failed (i don’t know why, relationships weren’t saved.). So i try this approach that seems to work (with few interactions it works perfectly). I tested it with 50000 users.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: A generic EXC_BAD_ACCESS with no extra info. It occurs in “self.user = user” line (it’s a relationship) after 2000 or 3000 iterations

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233452/coredata-difference-between-backgroundcontext-and-child-context-with-privateque) might be of interest